# Convert a collection of models to an array of models

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have two models, `Post` and `Comment`; many comments belong to a single post. I'm trying to access all comments associated with a post as an array.

I have the following, which gives a collection.

`$comments_collection = $post->comments()->get()`

How would I turn this `$comments_collection` into an array? Is there a more direct way of accessing this array through eloquent relationships?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray) of eloquent as below.

The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays

```
$comments_collection = $post->comments()->get()->toArray()
```

From Laravel Docs:

> toArray also converts all of the collection's nested objects that are an instance of Arrayable to an array. If you want to get the raw underlying array, use the [all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-all) method instead.

Comment: Sometimes this method throws exception when there is no data.

Comment: Can you tell me the case where it throws an expection. I tried with null data but doesn't throw an exception

Comment: Nit-pick: if the array elements implement `\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable`, they will be converted into arrays, too, recursively. That includes Eloquent models.

Comment: This shouldn't be the top answer. `->toArray()` does not convert the collection to an array, it converts the whole contents into arrays, including the items of the collection.
`->all()` should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @SebastienC. OP had asked the way to convert collection to an array. So, `toArray()` is fine for that. Also, I have updated the answer with documentation.

Comment: If query does not have any record then toArray() does not work on NULL record and returns error.

Comment: Don't use `toArray()`. The returned array is more of a collection. The correct answer should be using `all()`

Answer (score 49):

Use `all()` method - it's designed to return items of Collection:

```
/**
 * Get all of the items in the collection.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function all()
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

Comment: but is it in array?

Comment: Yes @JovylleBermudez. It is an Array of Objects

Comment: This is the right solution for me since I need an array of models, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$comments_collection = $post->comments()->get()->toArray();
```

see this can help you
[toArray() method in Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: If query does not have any record then toArray() does not work on NULL record and returns error.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]);
$collection->toArray();
```

Reference is https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-toarray

Originally from Laracasts website https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-convert-this-collection-to-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Usually we are getting collections from a database query. Other proposed solutions like `->toArray()` will actually read data from the database as an array, then create collection from this array, and then the user will convert this collection back to array.

But we can don't create collection at all by subclassing some classes and redefine some methods.

In Laravel 10.* `get()` @ `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php` contain next code:

```
    /**
     * Execute the query as a "select" statement.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function get($columns = ['*'])
    {
        $builder = $this->applyScopes();

        // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
        // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded, which will solve the
        // n+1 query issue for the developers to avoid running a lot of queries.
        if (count($models = $builder->getModels($columns)) > 0) {
            $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
        }

        return $builder->getModel()->newCollection($models);
    }
```

`applyScopes()` and `getModels()` are public methods so you can use next code:

```
$array = MyModel::where('foo', '=', 1)->applyScopes()->getModels($columns);
```

as low level access to DB w/o loading relationships (you also can load with it).

Also expressions like `MyModel::where(...)` returns specific query builder `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. You can redefine it by using trait:

```
class CustomEloquentBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
{

    /**
     * Based on original get method of Eloquent query builder
     *
     * @param string[] $columns
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function getArray(string|array $columns = ['*']): array
    {
        return $this->applyScopes()->getModels($columns);
    }

}

trait CustomEloquentQueryBuilder
{
    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
     */
    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        return new CustomEloquentBuilder($query);
    }
}

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use CustomEloquentQueryBuilder;
}
```

In cases when you need to read database w/o Eloquent you need to use custom `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Query\Expression;

class CustomQueryBuilder extends Builder
{

    public static function table(\Closure|Builder|Expression|string $table, ?string $as = null): CustomQueryBuilder
    {
        $connection = app('db')->connection();
        return (new CustomQueryBuilder($connection, $connection->getQueryGrammar(), $connection->getPostProcessor()))->from($table, $as);
    }

    /**
     * Based on original get method
     *
     * @param  array|string  $columns
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function getArray(array|string $columns = ['*']): array
    {
        return $this->onceWithColumns(Arr::wrap($columns), function () {
            return $this->processor->processSelect($this, $this->runSelect());
        });
    }

}

$array = CustomQueryBuilder::table('my_table')->where('foo', '=', 1)->getArray();
```

As I know you also can add custom `getArray()` method to DB via MACRO, but I'm not tested it.

All this methods really return arrays instead creating collections and then converting it to array.

Comment: What does this have to do with converting a Collection to an array?

Comment: We are getting collections from a database query. Other proposed solutions will actually read data from the database as an array, then create collection from this array, and then the user will convert this collection back to array. I’m writing about how to immediately get the result of query as array. Without collections at all.

Comment: Ok knowing that the code makes more sense. You should [edit] your question to include an explanation of what the code does and how it improves on other methods, as well as examples of use.

Comment: I added explanation. My answer contains examples of use

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect($comments_collection)`.

Else, try `json_encode($comments_collection)` to convert to json.

Answer (score -1):

Just doing an all() on the collection returns an array, like so:

```
$comments_collection = $post->comments()->all();
```

I'm on Laravel 10.5.0 and this works well for me.

Comment: This advice [was posted years ago by @eithed on this same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58992095/2943403).

Answer (score -1):

For nested collection (for example when we call query builder get method) we can make things simpler by adding a macro to collection type. we assume our collection is collection of stdClass objects.

for this, add this code to the `boot()` method in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Collection::macro('toNestedArray', function () {
        return $this->transform(function ($item, int $key) {
            return (array)$item;
        });
    });
```

just note this code would convert just one level nested stdClass to array. you can tune the code for your needs

Answer (score -2):

Try **collect** function in array like:

```
$comments_collection = collect($post->comments()->get()->toArray());
```

this methods can help you

**toArray()** with **collect()**

Comment: If query does not have any record then toArray() does not work on NULL record and returns error.