# How to convert a collection or object to an array in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my query:

`$data=Auth::user()->roles()->with('permissions')->get()->pluck('permissions');
 return $data;`

The output of the query is as following:

```
 [
  [
   {
    id: 2,
    name: "Read",
    slug: "Read",
    description: "This is Simple Read Permission",
     pivot: {
     role_id: 2,
     permission_id: 2,
     },
    },
   {
    id: 3,
    name: "Update",
    slug: "Update",
    description: "This is Simple Update Permission",

    pivot: {
     role_id: 2,
     permission_id: 3,
    },
   },
  ]
 ]
```

Now I want to convert this into an array. I've already use the `map()` and `toArray()` function, but the result still remains the same format.

How can I convert this collection in to an array?

Comment: What about `->all()` ? [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-all)

Comment: Just a guess here, but I'd have the pluck('permissions') before the actual get()

Comment: I've use the `pluck` before `get()` but it's shows error.. @OleHaugset

Comment: @Gabrielle All the permissions of the user is what you really need right? If so do you use a package?

Comment: Do you want every single element in the objects to be an array? You will have to convert it recursively in this case. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/victorbstan/744478)

Comment: When you return an array from a route/controller method in Laravel it will automatically convert it to JSON. The example in your question is just the JSON representation of the array.

Comment: @RossWilson I think the OP wants it to be a native array, not an object. That way you can use array accessors instead of object properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel collection to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284974/laravel-collection-to-array)

Comment: @Gabrielle Can you tell us what you want to do with the array e.g. is it a response to an ajax request or an api call, or are you going to pass it to a view/blade file? As mentioned in an earlier comment, returning just an array/object/collection from a Route/controller method (used for the route) it will be converted to a JSON response, however, if you're passing it to a blade file it won't be. We just need to know a bit more about what you're planning to do to be able to help you :)