# How do I convert this collection to an array in Laravel 5.2

Tags: collections, laravel-5

I've upgraded my app from Laravel 4.2 to 5.2. This line in the controller grabbed a list of directories:

```
 $directories = DirectoryModel::lists('name', 'id');
```

and I sent it compacted to the blade to generate a pull-down menu in the blade:

```
 return view('citations.createBlank', compact('citation'), compact('directories'));
```

In the blade, I used the Form collective to generate the pulldown menu as follows:

```
Form::select('directory_id', [null=>'Please Select'] + $directories, $citation->directory_id, ['id'=>'directory','class'=>'form-control input-sm js-basic-single','required'])
```

In Laravel 4.2, $directories was an array in the blade. Now in 5.2 it's a Collection (object) and the blade is throwing an error: Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int.

How do I convert this to an array in the Controller? Or do I need to rewrite my blade to generate the pulldown differently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel collection to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284974/laravel-collection-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `->toArray()` method:

```
$directories = DirectoryModel::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

By the way:

The `lists` method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to `pluck`. The method signature remains the same.

So you better use `pluck` instead of `lists`, it's deprecated:

```
$directories = DirectoryModel::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

[Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade)