# How to turn a collection into an array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm not sure if my title is correctly done, but what I'm trying to do is get all the notifications that a user didn't read.
I have 2 tables the first table is notifications and the second one is read_notifications.

Here is my code in User.php model

```
$read = DB::table('read_notifications')->select('notification_id')->where('user_id', $this->id)->get();
$unread = Notification::whereNotIn('id', $read)->get();
```

Here I'm getting all the notification IDs in the read_notifications table and I want to put them in the `$unread` statement.

The error I get when I do this is

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel collection to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284974/laravel-collection-to-array)

Comment: I did try that, but I still got the same error

Comment: Do you have set relations between `Notification` and `ReadNotification`? Is there `ReadNotification` model at all? I presume it can be done with `whereDoesntHave` method with properly set relations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification::whereNotIn('id', $read)->get();
```

`$read` is an object and `id` should be a string (or integer). You should use an `id` field from your `$read` object like `$read[$i]->id`.

Also `whereNotIn` needs an array as a second argument, so you need to collect your IDs from `$read` to an array like `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to get my ids to looks like `[1,2,3]`, so that I can use it in the `whereNotIn` statement

Answer (score 0):

for `whereNotIn` to work `$read` should be an array.

```
 $read = DB::table('read_notifications')->select('notification_id')->where('user_id', $this->id)->get();
foreach($read as $re)
   $ot[] = $re->notification_id;
$unread = Notification::whereNotIn('id', $ot)->get();
```

OR you can use `pluck`

```
 $read = DB::table('read_notifications')->where('user_id', $this->id)->pluck('notification_id');

 $unread = Notification::whereNotIn('id', $read)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. I found what I needed, I needed to use the pluck method.

Here is the updated code

```
$read = DB::table('read_notifications')->select('notification_id')->where('user_id', $this->id)->pluck('notification_id');
$unread = Notification::whereNotIn('id', $read)->get();
```