# Laravel Checking if Array or Collection is not Empty to run

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

I have an object of **$person** as below:

```
$person = Person::where('id', $id)->first();
```

According to which **$person** exists or not I load other data:

```
if($person) {
    $person->family_members = FamilyMemberController::FamilyMemberOf($person->id);
} else {
    $person->family_members = [];
}
```

In the view file, I check the **$person->family_members** if not empty and exists to add a generated value :

```
if(!empty(array_filter($person->family_members))) {
    // my code
}
```

But it throws an error:

> array_filter(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

I need to check this **$person->family_members** to make sure whether it's an array or a collection is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing code for ***if array** do something **if collection** do something* is the wrong way of implementation.

You can do two things.

1. use both returns as `collection()`
2. or either use both returns as an `array[]`

---

If collection

```
else {
    $person->family_members = collect();
}
```

If array

use `->toArray()` at the end of Eloquent. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285030/4595675)

---

> As well, I think you are confused with [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Maybe you are searching for [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) or [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains)

Answer (score 1):

Use count method

```
if(count($person->family_members)>0){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know your code, but given the error, it's safe to assume your method returns a `Collection`. You can see available methods in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections). However, if you need it as `array`, all you need to do is call `->toArray()` on the result `Collection`. Then you can use `array_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

What about just doing

```
if(!$person->family_members){
   // your code here
}
```

or

```
if($person->family_members){
   // your code here
} else {
   // code of "if it's empty" goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count() function to return a count of an index. ex

```
if(count($person->family_members)){
    //do your true algo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why you are using the empty method ?!** Try this:

```
$person->family_members = $person ? FamilyMemberController::FamilyMemberOf($person->id) : null;
if($person->family_members){ // your code }
```

Try simple ways in Programming ;)